# Random Access to VB6 Binary Data from Java

Tags: java, vb6, vb6-migration, random-access

I am trying to write a distributed application in Java, however the program I am writing is replacing a VB6 equivalent. The data files that are used are live files containing binary data written using VB6 put methods and are constantly in use by several applications.

I have successfully retrieved text from the file by reading an entire record (160 bytes) into the byte array buf. Then using the following line to extract text fields

`new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buf, 15, 40), "ISO-8859-1");`

I also need to extract the VB6 data types Boolean, Double, Integer, Long and Single. Eventually I will probably need datetime as well but not for the first stage. To do doubles I know that the endianess is Little endian rather than big in VB6 so I have the following function

```
public static double toDouble(byte[] bytes) {
    return ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getDouble();
}
```

The first few data fields are strings then 2 double, the output at the moment is:

```
Barcode: 1            
Dept Code: 18
Description: MISC NON VAT             
Trade Price: 0.0
Retail Price: 0.009999999776482582
```

As you can see the first 3 are logical and match the content in the datafile. The trade price should be 0.0 so that is fine but retail price should be 0.01 which would be correct if I round it but, A. I am uncomfortable rounding price and vat info and B. I can't reasonably write any changes back to the file as if I am reading with a margin or error then I will probably be writing with the same margin of error. I also tried manually bit-shifting but for a double Java complains if I try and shift more than 31 bits which of course I need to in order to do 56.

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Comment: I just thought I should add, I know this sort of thing has been dealt with on this site before and I apologise for the similar question but my progress thus far has been due to other questions and like I mentioned in the question, what I have done is not quite right and I can't see why.

Comment: the best solution of all would be if a Java library to do this sort of thing already existed but I can't find one.

Comment: I would love to give a sample of the data file but as it is mostly nulls and binary it does not exactly lend itself to being posted. If there is a place I can share the binary data please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were trying to do this, I think I'd write a VB6StreamReader that encapsulates the reading of VB6 primitives and deals with the quirks in the data that result from in the way the data is written via Put in VB6.

In regards to rounding, most floating point numbers are represented in the way you described.  Are you concerned that VB6 encodes floating point numbers in a non-standard way?  Visual Basic uses the IEEE 754.

---

Useful IEEE-754 calculator:  http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am trying to make a general class to do it for all files which is why I said I will probably want datetime eventually. But what concerns me here is the possible loss of precision. If VB6 represents 0.01 as 0.009999999776482582 in Java's eyes then rounding to a few DP is probably okay but lets say I want to increase this to 0.07. My instinct is that it should probably look something more like 0.069999999776482582 otherwise VB6 might consider it 0.070000000334628528 or something which if I keep writing it back and forth the difference would build until problematic.

Comment: The bytes 0,0,0,64,-31,122,-124,63 give 0.01 in VB6 but 0.009999999776482582 using what I have so far in Java, what is the difference and how can I account for it is more precisely what I am asking

Comment: I placed the bytes you mentioned (hex 00,00,00,40,E1,7A,84,3F) into a file and read them in VB6 with and output to a MsgBox and got .00999999977648258.

Comment: maybe it is how I am getting the bytes in in the first place then, In 6 I am just using get into a custom type, I had assumed that Java read the bytes in properly, I will check it.

Comment: Are you sure that values in VB6 are what you say? Or could that simply be the value that is displayed?